# Increase dot legend size

Tags: plotting, legending

I use the following code to plot my graphic. I want to increase the size of the point in my legend. When I used `LabelStyle`, it increase only the text and not the point in the legend. How can I increase the point of my legend with the text ?

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
func2[file_String /; FileExistsQ[file], colors_] := 
  Module[{data, formatted}, 
 formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #3]} & @@@ data;
   ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, Joined -> False, 
    PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{FileBaseName[file]}], 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[colors, PointSize[0.01]]}, , 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 34}]];
```

Comment: The function alone is not very helpful without example data. Moreover, please focus on the necessary details for answering the question. For example, everything involving file import it irrelevant.

Comment: You are probably looking for `LegendMarkerSize`.

Comment: I use `Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]` and tried `LgendMarkerSize` but I get the following output `OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option LegendMarkerSize for ErrorListPlot`.

Comment: @Bigprophete, try adapting `LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {Style["label 1", 16], Style["label 2", 24]}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}, LegendMarkerSize -> 50]` to your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A request:** we have seen the code you posted in almost all of your questions so far. Please use fake data like the one used below (instead of files that we cannot access) to give minimal examples of the problem you are facing and the  desired result.

The relevant part of the question can be solved using the `LegendMarkers` option inside `LineLegend`:

```
LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {Style["label 1", 12], Style["label 2", 24]}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}, LegendMarkerSize -> 50]
```

[image]

Combined with made-up data for the irrelevant parts:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[100, {20, 4}];
formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4/10, #3/10]} & @@@ data;
colors = Red;

ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, Joined -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Style["label 1", 24]}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}, LegendMarkerSize -> 50], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[colors, PointSize[0.03]], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 34}]
```

[image]

Comment: I see. Ok, sorry... I will try to put example and files next time.